# How to make API call in response to state being updated by useReducer

Tags: reactjs

A React reducer must be a pure function, so cannot make API calls. So, what is the right way to make an API call in in response to some state that is changed by my reducer?

From the React documentation:

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === 'incremented_age') {
    return {
      age: state.age + 1
    };
  }
  throw Error('Unknown action.');
}

export default function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { age: 42 });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'incremented_age' })
      }}>
        Increment age
      </button>
      <p>Hello! You are {state.age}.</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

When `state.age` changes, I want to make an API call to change this in my database.

This is a trivial example, and in this case I could not use a reducer, and instead I could make an API call to update the age, then update my state when my database notifies me of a change. However, in a more complex situation I want to use the reducer for processing the user inputs, and as a result (depending on the resulting state) make a call to the database.

How can I structure this, without making the reducer impure by putting the API call inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `apicall` in a `useEffect()` with dependency as `[state.age]` so when age is updated the `apicall` will be triggered. If condition is crucial so that it does not trigger the first time when component is mounted.

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === "incremented_age") {
    return {
      age: state.age + 1
    };
  }
  throw Error("Unknown action.");
}

export default function Counter() {
  const INITIAL_STATE = { age: 42 };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.age !== INITIAL_STATE.age) {
      //Put api call here
      console.log("age updated", state);
    }
  }, [state.age]);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({ type: "incremented_age" });
        }}
      >
        Increment age
      </button>
      <p>Hello! You are {state.age}.</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aniket, makes sense, but what if `state.age` is an array where only one element has been changed in the reducer, and I need to make an API call for just that one element?

In useEffect I could search through the array looking for a change, but it's inefficient, when the reducer knew exactly what had changed. Or I could create some extra state in the reducer (`state.workForUseEffectToDo`) which contains instructions for the useEffect (which could be cleared by the reducer once the effect is done) but it feels like a lot of complexity and not how it's designed to work.

Comment: See, you can't ask hypothetical questions like that. Please provide a proper code for the situation you are describing, do your work and if it doesn't work or has issue please specify them here

Comment: Fair point @Aniket - I've got a large code base and can't easily reduce my exact problem to something that can be posted, but thought that the example above demonstrated the issue. It turns out it doesn't, so will try to create a better example and post a new question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pancake if possible, share your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: So what you are saying is use have `age=[1, 2, 3]` initially and you used reducer to updated it to `age=[1,2,8]`. Now, you just want to fetch the third element from db. Is that correct?

Comment: I've created a codesandbox with a [more complex example](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-agnesi-t6t7pm?file=/src/App.js). Not sure if this is better as a new question, but hopefully this illustrates my issue better. See on line 58 - I want to make an API call at this point, but it is not permitted in a reducer - so how should I make this sort of API call? To check through the whole state in a useEffect is very inefficient, both in runtime and in terms of code duplication.